# Calling a method inside of a method while both are in the same PHP class

Tags: php, function, methods

I assume this is possible with PHP but I am having some trouble getting it to work. I am trying to minimize the amount of code that is being duplicated by creating only one instance of the html that is supposed to display inside of a php class method. This is the part I only want to create once.

```
public function display($dbCon){
    $content = $obj->content;
    $contentSEO = $obj->contentSEO;
    $contentLink = $obj->contentLink;
        if(!empty($content) && !empty($contentSEO) && !empty($contentLink)){
            $content = str_replace("$contentSEO","<a href=\"$contentLink\"><small>$contentSEO</small></a>",$content);
            printf("%s", $content);
        } elseif(!empty($content) && empty($contentSEO) && !empty($contentLink)){
            $content = str_replace("$content","<a href=\"$contentLink\">$content</a>",$content);
            printf("%s", $content);
        } elseif(!empty($content) && !empty($contentSEO) && empty($contentLink)){
            $content = str_replace("$contentSEO","<small>$contentSEO</small>",$content);
            printf("%s", $content);
        } elseif(!empty($content) && empty($contentSEO) && empty($contentLink)){
            printf("%s", $content);
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
```

Now this is inside of a class and I want the following method to call on this one above after the sql query is performed. The goal with my intent here is that in case I need to call on a similar function with the same HTML, I can simply just call on this one already created instead of coding it all over again. The second portion looks like this.

```
public function content1($dbCon){
        if($res = $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE status = '1' and id = '1'")) {
            while($obj = $res->fetch_object()) {
                $this->display($dbCon);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the simple way would be to simply add them both in the same function and this does work. like the example below.

```
public function content1($dbCon){
        if($res = $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE status = '1' and id = '1'")) {
            while($obj = $res->fetch_object()) {
                $content = $obj->content;
                $contentSEO = $obj->contentSEO;
                $contentLink = $obj->contentLink;
                if(!empty($content) && !empty($contentSEO) && !empty($contentLink)){
                    $content = str_replace("$contentSEO","<a href=\"$contentLink\"><small>$contentSEO</small></a>",$content);
                    printf("%s", $content);
                } elseif(!empty($content) && empty($contentSEO) && !empty($contentLink)){
                    $content = str_replace("$content","<a href=\"$contentLink\">$content</a>",$content);
                    printf("%s", $content);
                } elseif(!empty($content) && !empty($contentSEO) && empty($contentLink)){
                    $content = str_replace("$contentSEO","<small>$contentSEO</small>",$content);
                    printf("%s", $content);
                } elseif(!empty($content) && empty($contentSEO) && empty($contentLink)){
                    printf("%s", $content);
                } else {
                    echo "Error";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, doing it this way would require me to always copy and paste the same code. when it is needed. I rather just create the function with the query and call on the if statement function to display the HTML. I thought I could simply call it like so inside of the function right after the while statement like so:

```
$this->display($dbCon);
```

But instead I keep getting the same error message I planted in the code in case it didn't work. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you need to call `$this->display($obj);` instead of `$this->display($dbCon);`.

Comment: No, I tried it, I also tried a couple other variations, you gave me some ideas as to why it could be broken but those weren't fruitful either.